# Structural pattern matching on dictionaries using `**`

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Is there a reasoning for this?

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dct_1 = {'a': 1}
dct_2 = {'b': 2}
match dct:
  case {'b': 2, **dct_1}: print("using {'b': 2, **dct_1}", dct)
```

outputs,

```
using {'b': 2, **dct_1} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

but,

```
match dct:
  case {**dct_1, 'b': 2}: print("using {**dct_1, 'b': 2}", dct)
```

gives error,

```
    case {**dct_1, 'b': 2}: print("using {**dct_1, 'b': 2}", dct)
                   ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and,

```
match dct:
  case {**dct_1, **dct_2}: print("using {**dct_1, **dct_2))}", dct)
```

gives error,

```
    case {**dct_1, **dct_2}: print("using {**dct_1, **dct_2))}", dct)
                   ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using python2? I cant reproduce it in python3.

Comment: Python 3.11.0a7

Answer (score 2):

This is just how the syntax for [mapping patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-mapping_pattern) is defined.

> At most one double star pattern may be in a mapping pattern. The double star pattern must be the last subpattern in the mapping pattern.

If there were multiple double-star patterns, it would be ambiguous which items should match which patterns. I suspect it's just too much trouble to decide which items a non-final double-star pattern should match without matching the explicit patterns first, so it is just disallowed. Note that a mapping pattern is *not* an expression, so there isn't a strong need to support as much flexibility as a dict display supports.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't have been *that* hard to support. In `{**a, **b, ...}` key-values "propagate" from left-to-right, overwriting already existing keys along the way. So it just means a multiple double-star pattern would need to do some work before being able to be tested against. I think it's a matter of "do we really need it".

Comment: Given that the syntax had to be duplicated from the display syntax anyway, they probably took the opportunity to omit what wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Match statements don’t work the way you’re expecting.**

Python `match` statements match against patterns, not values (although literals and **dotted** identifiers are valid patterns). Any non-dotted identifiers are considered *capture patterns*.

For example:

```
match {'a': 1, 'b': 2}:
    case {'a': a, **rest}: print(a, rest)
```

outputs

```
1 {'b': 2}
```

Going back to your code, `case {'b': 2, **dct_1}:` doesn’t expand `dct_1`; it *binds* the remaining keys to `dct_1`.

I suggest [reading the PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/) for more details and examples.